# Java safest way to check client jar server side

Tags: java, network-programming

I am creating a client-server application in which I have to make sure that the client has the exact same file I give them. 
I was thinking about sending a hash or jar size to the server, but that can easily be bypassed with reverse engineering the code. 
Is there a way to ensure that they have the same file yet they can't hack it?

Comment: No.  You can only make it difficult for them to do so. Think of it this way - if a malicious user could RE your code, he could run it in an emulator and generate whatever response you are looking for, then send it and run his own malicious code anyway.  That's a little silly, but it illustrates the impossibility of restricting the user in the way you want.

Comment: That said, you may want to look into signed/encrypted jar files to prevent tampering - or at least make it very difficult.

Comment: Thank you, @BadZen! I'll definitely look into those.

Comment: And ask yourself why. Is this a protocol issue? Or a licensing issue? If it's a protocol issue, you don't really care, as long as the client implements the protocol correctly, and it is probably a bad idea to insist on one specific code implementation. If i's a licensing issue, what you need is authentication of a licence, not verification of a JAR file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Most likely no, at least not without e.g. having access to their hardware and locking it down some way, like with modern gaming consoles. Take PC software, especially games, as an example. Pretty much every game ships with copy protection, yet they all can be found for download free of charge in certain areas of the internet, with copy protection removed. Yes, most of them can't be used for online play anymore, but that's mostly because you need an account that you'd only get when buying the game. Then there are modifications to online games that will give you an advantage over other players, even though there are counter measurements by the game companies, like additional software that is running on the player's computer, scanning for suspicious activity. It's a race between the "hackers" and game vendors, but neither side can win. And we're talking about software made my multi-million dollar companies that should have the resources to make their software hacking proof, if it were possible.

For the case of Java applications, it's comparably easy to modify them, even if you're using obfuscation techniques or signing, as Java byte code simply is much easier to analyze, understand and turn back into Java source files than machine code generated by C/C++ compilers.

Comment: Thank you, I think your and BadZen's answer is enough for me. Seems like I'll have to do it the hard way.